# Create a rectangle based on user's character input

Tags: c

I have to write a program in C (which I'm new in) so that the user enters the number of lines and columns and the character they want to display as the rectangle, for example, a 6 lines and 6 columns asterisk rectangle.

Here is the assignment in detail.

> The first thing your program will do is print a menu of choices for
> the user. You may choose your own version of the wording or order of
> choices presented, but each choice given in the menu must match the
> following:A function that prompts the user to enter a single
> character. The return value of the function be a char and will return
> the character value entered by the user.This return value will be
> stored in a local variable, C, in main(). The initial default value of
> this character will be ' ' (blank or space character).
>
> A function that prompts the user to enter a numerical value between 1
> and 15 (inclusive). If the user enters a value outside this range, the
> user is prompted to re-enter a value until a proper value is entered.
> The return value of the function be an int and will return the value
> entered by the user. This return value will be stored in a local
> variable, N, in main(). The initial default value of this character
> will be 0.
>
> Two "Print Rectangle" functions. Each function will take the current
> integer value N and character value C as input parameters. The return
> values of these functions will be void. The functions will print
> rectangles of N lines and columns using the input character C. The
> Border Only function will print the rectangle with the just the
> border. The Filled In function will print the rectangle as a solid
> rectangle. For example, if the integer value N = 6, and the character
> value C = '*' and the Filled In type is called, the following
> rectangle will be printed:

Here is my code so far. What I am doing wrong and am I coding the program correctly?

```
       #include <stdio.h>
       #include <stdlib.h>

       char enterSingleChar();
       int enterNumValue();
       void printRectanlgeOne(int N, char C);
       void printRectangleTwo(int N, char C);

     int main()
    `enter code here`{       
        char userChoice;
        int N = 0;
        char C = ' ';
        
        fprintf(stdout, "Please choose one of the following choices below \n");     
        fprintf(stdout, "Enter/Change Character (C/c)\n");
        fprintf(stdout, "Enter/Change Number (N/n) \n");
        fprintf(stdout, "Print Rectangle Type 1 (Border Only), enter 1 \n");
        fprintf(stdout, "Print Rectangle Type 2 (Filled in), etner 2 \n");
        fprintf(stdout, "Quit Program (Q/q) \n");
                
        scanf("%c", &userChoice);
        
        switch(userChoice)
        {       
                case 'C':
                case 'c':
                        enterSingleChar();
                        break;
                case 'N':
                case 'n':
                        enterNumValue();
                        break;
                case '1':
                        printRectangleOne(N,C);
                        break;
                case '2':
                        printRectangleTwo(N,C);
                        break;
        break;
                case 'Q':
                case 'q':
                        fprintf(stdout, "The program will now quit\n");
                        exit(1);
                default:
                        break;
        }               
}       

char enterSingleChar()
{
        char singleChar = ' ';
        fprintf(stdout, "Please enter a single character \n");
        scanf("%c", &singleCharC);
        return singleChar;
}

int enterNumValue()
{
        int numValue;
        fprintf(stdout, "Please enter a numerical value between 1 and 15 inclusively \n");
    
scanf("%d", &numValue);

        while(numValue <= 1 || numValue >= 15)
        {
                fprintf(stdout, "You have entered an invalid num \n");
                fprintf(stdout, "Please try again \n");
                fprintf(stdout, "Please enter a numerical value between 1 and 15 inclusively \n");
                scanf("%d", &numValue);
        }
        return numValue;
}

void printRectangleOne(int N, char C)
{
        int i;
        int j;
        for(i = 0; i <= N; i++)
        {
                fprintf(stdout, &C);

                for(j = 0; i <= N; i++)
                {
fprintf(stdout, &C);
                }
        }
        printf();
}

void printRectangleTwo(int N, char C)
{

}
```

Comment: So, what is your specific problem?

Comment: In printRectangleOne function, look at the second loop: for(j = 0; i <= N; i++)
 There is a mix of j and i

Comment: How do the variables `C` and `N` ever change?

Comment: `fprintf(stdout, &C)`? Didn't your compiler warn you about that?

Answer (score 1):

## Use your compiler

If you try and compile that code with all warnings enabled, it starts spewing out errors which you should correct before going on:

> ```
> test.c:10:5: error: stray ‘`’ in program
>      `enter code here`{
>      ^
> test.c: In function ‘main’:
> test.c:10:6: error: unknown type name ‘enter’
>      `enter code here`{
>       ^
> ```

And:

> ```
> test.c: In function ‘main’:
> test.c:34:25: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printRectangleOne’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>                          printRectangleOne(N,C);
>                          ^
> test.c: In function ‘enterSingleChar’:
> test.c:53:22: error: ‘singleCharC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>          scanf("%c", &singleCharC);
> ```

## Check your input

One problem that I can see is that when using `scanf` to read from standard input, **also the Enter key will be put in the queue**.

So you are asked,

```
Enter one character:
Enter another character:
```

and you type:

<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

and you expect the two characters to be A and B. What is really in the input queue could be, depending on platforms (I'm not sure):

```
A\r\nB\r\n  (*six* characters!)
A\nB\n      four characters
A\rB\r      four characters
```

Also, if you use one of those spurious characters (e.g. "\n", which is **newline**) to draw a 3x3 rectangle around the character "C", you will actually send to the output three empty lines (the top row), one empty line (the left border of the central line), a "C", and another four empty lines.

Which can be quite puzzling.

You do not state in your question what your problem actually *is*, but check your input routines, should any of the above symptoms make itself known.

## Other problems

```
void printRectangleOne(int N, char C)
{
        int i;
        int j;
        for (i = 0; i <= N; i++)
        {
                // Why do you output this C here?
                fprintf(stdout, &C);
                // You are checking and incrementing i here, not j.
                for(j = 0; i <= N; i++)
                {
                     // fprintf does not work this way. Use
                     // putchar(C);
                     // instead.
                     fprintf(stdout, &C);
                }
        }
        // I don't think this is going to work. Use either
        // putchar('\n') or printf("\n") to get a newline.
        printf();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest an iterative approach. If you run and write code together without compiling then debugging would be difficult. Hence start with a simple complete program.

I think the problem description is clear with different tasks. You could first start with the menu and then ensure it works fine before adding another feature to your code. This also provides you better learning and new features.

Comment: I'm leaving my answer as it contains some pointers I think are useful, but I'm upvoting yours because you suggested the correct **approach**,  which will be much more useful to the OP than fixing this one program.